# Flink output selector has strange behavior

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a stream with two forks, thus two SplitStreams.

Here is the code :

```
static final class MyOutputSelector1 implements OutputSelector<Long> {

    @Override
    public Iterable<String> select(Long value) {
        List<String> outputs = new ArrayList<>();
        if (value < 5) {
            outputs.add("valid1");
        }
        else {
            outputs.add("error1");
        }
        return outputs;
    }
}

static final class MyOutputSelector2 implements OutputSelector<Long> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Iterable<String> select(Long value) {
        List<String> outputs = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (value == 2) {
            outputs.add("valid2");
        }
        else {
            outputs.add("error2");
        }
        return outputs;
    }
}

@Test
public void outputSelectorTest() throws Exception {
    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    env.setParallelism(1);


    SplitStream<Long> split1 = env.generateSequence(1, 11).split(new MyOutputSelector1());
    DataStream<Long> stream11 = split1.select("valid1");
    stream11.print();

    SplitStream<Long> split2 = stream11.split(new MyOutputSelector2());
    DataStream<Long> stream21 = split2.select("valid2");
    stream21.print();
    DataStream<Long> stream22 = split2.select("error2");
    stream22.printToErr();

    env.execute();
}
```

And here is the input I get when I execute this code :

[Program output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIeVO.png)

My source is a list of integers between 1 and 11.
I expect stream11 to contain only integers less than 5. Which seems to be ok when I print it.
I expect stream21 to contain 2, which seems to be the case as two "2" are printed.
However, I would expect stream22 to contain all integers less than 5 except two but all integers between 1 and 11 are printed.

Why does it behave like that? I thought the first selector would have kept only integers from 1 to 4 in the stream but integers from 5 to 11 reappears after the last split...

To sum up, here is what I get and what I expect :

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pncT2.png)

There is probably a mechanism I do not understand. Is there any solution ? Should I use filters instead ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you found a bug. I could reproduce the issue with Flink 1.1.3 and the current master branch (Flink 1.2-SNAPSHOT).

I filed a JIRA issue: [FLINK-5031](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-5031) to track the bug.